# Why is ArrayUtils.add not adding the element here

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-lang

I use `ArrayUtils.add(double[], double)` with some frequency. Apparently I have a blind spot for why it's not working here. Can anyone help?

```
double[] reliableNeighborValues = new double[1];
for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    if (pixelInfo[j] > 0) {
        System.out.println("pre add array length "+reliableNeighborValues.length);
        for (int k = 0; k < reliableNeighborValues.length; k++) {
            System.out.println("-- "+reliableNeighborValues[k]);
        }
        ArrayUtils.add(reliableNeighborValues, pixelInfo[j]);
        System.out.println("reliable neighbor "+j+" "+pixelInfo[j]+" array length "+reliableNeighborValues.length);
        for (int k = 0; k < reliableNeighborValues.length; k++) {
            System.out.println("-- "+reliableNeighborValues[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
pre add array length 1

-- 0.0

reliable neighbor 0 5.3364882 array length 1

-- 0.0
```

Comment: you use _ArrayUtils.add(double[], double)_ and you are using _pixelInfo[j]_ an array in 2nd argument?

Comment: @BhavikShah: He's not passing complete array, but the value at index `j`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Arrays cannot be expanded in Java, so the method returns an updated copy of the array, that you are currently discarding.

```
  reliableNeighborValues = 
     ArrayUtils.add(reliableNeighborValues, pixelInfo[j]);
```

Same deal as with the String manipulation functions.

Comment: Good grief that's it. Thanks very much!